# multiple fields not all empty

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have three fields, used for initiating a search, any two of which can be empty, but I need to check to make sure the user has filled out *something*.

So, I have FirstName, LastName, and an ID number. The user should be able to search by any one, two or three of these fields, but I want to trap it if they click Submit without entering anything.

I'm fairly new to .NET, but as near as I can tell this means writing a custom validation. Validation attributes don't appear to be sufficient in themselves.

Is that the way to go? If it is, or if some other approach is better, could someone kindly supply some guidance?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It's fine that you edited the title, but I don't see how I'm to know which words are tags and which are not while I'm still typing the title. But I shall try to pay attention next time.

Comment: Simply ask yourself if you are adding words to the title for the purpose of categorizing the question. Then don't use those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the IValidatableObject interface on your search model.

Example:

```
public class SearchModel: IValidatableObject
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Field1) && string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Field2) && string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Field3))
            yield return new ValidationResult(("At least one field required.", new[] { "Field1", "Field2", "Field3" })

    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel searchModel)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      //Search
   }
   else
   {
       return View(searchModel);
   }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model SearchModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field1)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field1)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field2)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field2)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field2)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Field3)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Field3)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Field3)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: That's an extremely detailed answer, for which thanks. In trying to implement it, I find that the controller thinks there is no way into the else condition, and the compiler doesn't recognize "searchModel" in the else clause. I can return searchModel to the View just fine in the main condition. This feels like C#101 here. What am I missing?

Comment: Code was too long so I only included one field.

public ViewResult FindStudents(Models.Student student)

{

 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
  var target = new BoiseStateLdapData(LdapServerPath, LdapServerUserName, LdapServerPassword, LdapBaseDn);
        var search = new SearchParam(BooleanOperator.AND);
        search.Add(FilterFactory.NewFilter(PrefixFactory.NewPrefix("employeeid"), Operator.EQ, new Id(student.StudentId + "*")));
  var results = target.GetLdapDataList(search, new string[] {"employeeid", "cn", "givenname", "sn"});
  return View(results);
 }
 else
 {
  return View(results);
 }

Comment: Erg. Now formatted.

public ViewResult FindStudents(Models.Student student)  
{  
 if (ModelState.IsValid)  
 {  
  var target = new BoiseStateLdapData(LdapServerPath, LdapServerUserName, LdapServerPassword, LdapBaseDn);  
        var search = new SearchParam(BooleanOperator.AND);  
        search.Add(FilterFactory.NewFilter(PrefixFactory.NewPrefix("employeeid"), Operator.EQ, new Id(student.StudentId + "*")));  
  var results = target.GetLdapDataList(search, new string[] {"employeeid", "cn", "givenname", "sn"});  
  return View(results);  
 }  
 else  
 {  
  return View(results);  
 }

Comment: Bloody hell. Okay. Look for the semicolons, I guess. Sorry about the formatting. MetaStackoverflow itself claimed two spaces work, but they obviously don't.

Comment: You are returning "results" if the modelstate is invalid, when "results" is not available in that context.  You need to return "student" to the view that was used to create the posting form, so that the validation errors on the "student" model can be rendered in that view.

Comment: That worked, after a bit of fussing. Returning from inside the IsValid was fine. Returning outside it was problematic. I couldn't return View(results). What worked was to return View("Index"), but I had to change the ViewResult to an ActionResult. All good now and many thx.

Comment: This helped, but here are a couple more issues:
   -The string method is "string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace".
   -There should be a ; at the end of the yield line.
Correcting these got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your essentially trying to validate the fields are valid before they submit, it is very possible.  You can build your own `Event Handler` to handle changes to those components, you can handle a `Notifier` on the button.

There are a lot of ways to implement such a feat.  A very simple and basic way to get you familiar with the conceptual notion is the *Error Provider*.

This component can be found in your toolbox, all you do is drag it to your Form.  Once it is there you can do the following to a `textbox`.

```
if(textbox1.text == String.EmptyOrNull)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textbox1, "Please enter valid field.");
}
else
{
    errorProvider1.Dispose();
    MessageBox.Show(textbox1.text);
}
```

Obviously that is a basic approach and will require refactoring, but that should do your task and familiarize yourself a bit more with C# and it's implementation.

Hopefully that helps.

---

**Update:**

I failed to see that one field can be null, or empty.  But your requiring the other two fields; you can simply do field validation as normal, but you would want to concatenate those results.

You would want to use the `&&` Operand.  As if both variables are true; then it will perform the task.  Where has the `||` will allow one to be false to validate.

```
if(textbox1.text == String.EmptyOrNull) && 
        (textbox2.text == String.EmptyOrNull) && 
        (textbox3.text == String.EmptyOrNull))
{
    // One field is Null or Empty, do something.
}
```

As I stated that is a basic way.  There are more efficient ways to handle such validation, but I'd start simple since you are new to C# and Microsoft .Net.

Comment: Thanks. I do see the logic here. I'm trying out Oliver's approach first but if I wind up using yours I'll post and vote up. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: @SkipKnox Olivers approach is a more advanced approach, it is better.  The goal is to understand the conceptual logic.  As long as our post help that is all that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [Fluent Validation](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/A-Quick-Introduction-to-Fluentvalidation-in-aspnet-mvc.aspx)